# iAds interfering functionality of Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, iad

Since I have enabled iAds in my trivia app, the background, which is supposed to change every time a new question is loaded no longer changes. When I comment out the canDisplayBannerAds line, it works again. Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var funFactLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var funFactButton: UIButton!
    let factBook = FactBook()
    let colorWheel = ColorWheel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        funFactLabel.text = factBook.randomFact()
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showFunFact() {
        let randomColor = colorWheel.randomColor()
        view.backgroundColor = randomColor
        funFactButton.tintColor = randomColor
        funFactLabel.text = factBook.randomFact()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `view.backgroundColor = randomColor` you should be using `originalContentView.backgroundColor = randomColor`

---

How I got the solution:

From the [documentation for `canDisplayBannerAds`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/canDisplayBannerAds)

> See Also
>
> `originalContentView`

And [`originalContentView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/originalContentView) says:

> When a view controller enables banner ads, the system puts the view controller’s content view inside of a new content view that the system manages. This allows the system to dynamically resize the original content view when a banner ad is displayed, as well as managing the display of the banner ad itself. This property provides access to the original content view, rather than the containing view that manages banner ad display.

Comment: Thanks David, That solved the issue! I know I'll be using this in the future as I put banner ads on all my other apps!  Thanks again!